# Short Integers in Python

Tags: python, memory-management, short

Python allocates integers automatically based on the underlying system architecture. Unfortunately I have a huge dataset which needs to be fully loaded into memory.

So, is there a way to force Python to use only 2 bytes for some integers (equivalent of C++ 'short')?

Comment: If you're doing any sort of manipulation of this huge dataset, you'll probably want to use [Numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/ "Numpy Home Page"), which has support for a wide variety of numeric types, and efficient operations on arrays of them.

Comment: just a heads up: C++'s short not 2 bytes width. It's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 45):

Nope.  But you can use short integers in arrays:

```
from array import array
a = array("h") # h = signed short, H = unsigned short
```

As long as the value stays in that array it will be a short integer.

- documentation for the [array module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/array)

Comment: A better and more complete answer than my own. :)

Comment: So, is an array('h') with only one element, the same as creating a short integer?

Comment: @Arnav: nope. that would be a PyObject + a short integer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Armin for pointing out the 'array' module. I also found the 'struct' module that packs c-style structs in a string:

From the documentation (https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
>>> unpack('hhl', '\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
>>> calcsize('hhl')
8
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use NumyPy's int as np.int8 or np.int16.

Comment: My name is numpy -with an umpy. All other data packages allow me to bump thee.

Answer (score 3):

Armin's suggestion of the array module is probably best.  Two possible alternatives:

- You can create an extension module yourself that provides the data structure that you're after.  If it's really just something like a collection of shorts, then
  that's pretty simple to do.
- You can
  cheat and manipulate bits, so that
  you're storing one number in the
  lower half of the Python int, and
  another one in the upper half. 
  You'd write some utility functions
  to convert to/from these within your
  data structure.  Ugly, but it can be made to work.

It's also worth realising that a Python integer object is not 4 bytes - there is additional overhead.  So if you have a really large number of shorts, then you can save more than two bytes per number by using a C short in some way (e.g. the array module).

I had to keep a large set of integers in memory a while ago, and a dictionary with integer keys and values was too large (I had 1GB available for the data structure IIRC).  I switched to using a IIBTree (from ZODB) and managed to fit it.  (The ints in a IIBTree are real C ints, not Python integers, and I hacked up an automatic switch to a IOBTree when the number was larger than 32 bits).

Comment: Can I use IIBTree without installing all of Zope?  Where do I get it?  What's an IOBTree?

Comment: Just install ZODB (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB3/3.8.0).  An IOBTree is a BTree that has integer keys (the I) and object values (the O).

Answer (score 1):

You can also store multiple any size of integers in a single large integer.

For example as seen below, in python3 on 64bit x86 system, 1024 bits are taking 164 bytes of memory storage. That means on average one byte can store around 6.24 bits. And if you go with even larger integers you can get even higher bits storage density. For example around 7.50 bits per byte with 2**20 bits wide integer.

Obviously you will need some wrapper logic to access individual short numbers stored in the larger integer, which is easy to implement.

One issue with this approach is your data access will slow down due use of the large integer operations.

If you are accessing a big batch of consecutively stored integers at once to minimize the access to large integers, then the slower access to long integers won't be an issue.

I guess use of numpy will be easier approach.

```
>>> a = 2**1024
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
164
>>> 1024/164
6.2439024390243905

>>> a = 2**(2**20)
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
139836
>>> 2**20 / 139836
7.49861266054521
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bytearray in python which is basically a C unsigned char array under the hood will be a better solution than using large integers. There is no overhead for manipulating a byte array and, it has much less storage overhead compared to large integers. It's possible to get storage density of 7.99+ bits per byte with bytearrays.

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = bytearray(2**32)
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
4294967353
>>> 8 * 2**32 / 4294967353
7.999999893829228
```