# How do I grab and store URL using C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a URL with multiple paths. For example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120250
```

I want to grab the URLS entire path and save it, then I want to call the URL later to duplicate the URL with all the paths. URL path is dynamic.
So for I have attempted this

```
        public Shared DuplicateTheChromeBrowser()
        {
            String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = (Keys.Alt + "d" + Keys.Enter);
            var SavedURL = Driver.Instance.Url();
            SavedURL.SendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
            return this;
        }
```

Comment: it's easier to just get the attribute of the href...  getAttribute("href").  (don't worry, relative paths will become absolute when you get them) You can store in an array and loop later if you like.  For opening a new tab you'll want to execute javascript (ex: window.open('about:blank', '_blank');) then switch the driver to that tab (window handle) and then navigate to the URL.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by *"grab the URLS entire path and save it, then I want to call the URL later to duplicate the URL with all the paths."* Nobody has answered your question, because we don't know enough information about how you expect this to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It saves the url of the page you go to or are on, then uses JS to create a new tab and send the URL from the original page to the new tab. Initbrowser() is my method for initiating an instance, so it its not necessarily part of the solution.

```
       public Shared DuplicateTheChromeBrowser()
        {
            //Initiate Browser Instance(this is my method, initiate how you did in our code which isnt visible in your question)
            IWebDriver driver = InitBrowser("chrome");
            //Go to page
            driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120250?params=testparam";
            //Save Current URL
            var SavedUrl = driver.Url;

            //Uses JS to open new tab
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

            //Changes Url of new tab to saved URL including param
            driver.Url = SavedUrl;
        }
```